# React Native UI Kitten Change hamburger icon color and Status bar icon colors

Tags: react-native

How can I change React Native UI Kitten Change hamburger icon color and Status bar icon colors?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I set the fill="#color" like a Svg and it work for me

```html
<MenuIcon fill="#fff" />
```